# How to pass keyword to landing page using PHP?

Tags: php

I'm using a landing page to redirect to my tracking url, how do I pass the keyword to my landing page which then passes it to my tracking link? Here is what my tracking link ends with:

```
&keyword={keyword}
```

I have tried doing http://www.foo.com?keyword={keyword} but no luck.

My landing page has this code:

```
<?php

header("Location: http://trackinglink.com&keyword={keyword}");

exit;
?>
```

Help please!!

edit: sorry for not being clear, I'm doing PPC and I need to use a landing page instead of direct linking (tracking url) so I need to be able to pass the keyword from the lander (which I'm gonna give to the PPC network) to my tracking link so I can see what keywords convert.

I need to know how to format the url to pass the keyword and what code to put into the landing page. thanks.

Comment: what does your code look like?

Comment: just dont use curly bracket or any parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

either the below, or I am not sure what you've asked at all

```
<?php

$keyword = 'location'; 

header("Location: http://foo.com?keyword=".$keyword);

exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

class saveKeys {

```
public function setKeyword($keyword) {
    $this->keyword = $keyword;
}

public function getKeyword() {
     return $this->keyword;
}
```

}

```
$keyword = new saveKeys();
$keyword->setKeyword($_GET['keyword']);
```

Now you saved the keyword in the setter and you can get it on the other page.

Comment: I don't think he was asking about OOP,

Comment: Just like you im not sure what he actually wants. But i think this can solve it.

Comment: fair enough, but what if `$_GET['keyword']` was not set? You are opening your self, for error in here `$keyword->setKeyword($_GET['keyword']);`

Comment: he can set it on the page it is available, if its not available he can use isset( ...

Comment: Well, that makes your answer incomplete :p anyway, the OP does not seem to care or even know what he is asking